# Can't use/debug SSH auth with Git for Windows

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash, putty, ssh-keys

I am using Git for Windows on Windows 10, I use GitExtensions as my GUI. To authenticate to various Git repositories, I use putty/pageant and I load up my keys into it. GitExtensions somehow works with this. Recently, I came across a Git repository at https://gitlab.example.com where GitExtensions tries to do `git clone` and tells me: `fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@` I also tried using gitbash to do the clone manually. When I attempt to call `git clone` manually, git bash will ask me for password to `git@gitlab.example.com`. My existing pageant session with loaded key is ignored.

I do not know how to debug or what the problem is. These are my current findings:

- GitExtensions has no git logging, so their cryptic message of `fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@` tells me nothing and I have no way to see the whole error that was returned.
- Git for Windows ignores my putty/pageant keys and keeps trying to look for keys in `.ssh` directory.
- If I create system environment variable `GIT_SSH` with path to  `plink.exe`, Git simply ignores it. It keeps looking for keys in `.ssh` dir.
- When I run `set GIT_SSH` in `cmd`, it prints out: `GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\PuTTY\plink.exe`.
- When I run `set GIT_SSH` in git bash, it prints out:  .
- When I run `export` in git bash, it will list variables and it will list `GIT_BASH` variable with correct value. I'm not sure what that means.

So currently I have a Windows machine with Git installed and I can't connect to a repository using putty/pageant SSH integration. I have no way of even seeing the error, because neither Git, or GitExtensions will allow me to see the error message and Git will not use my putty/pageant SSH keys for authentication.

I suspect that GitExtensions tries to use the SSH key through pageant.exe, but the server refuses it and responds with something like `git@gitlab.example.com password:` and GitExtensions detonates because it doesn't know what to do with it.

I also do not understand why gitbash in Windows doesn't use the running pageant.exe instance to get the SSH keys from. According to dozens of threads on this forum, it should be done by simply setting up the `GIT_SSH` environment variable, but that doesn't happen in my case.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Note that in bash (it's just "bash" as far as *using* it goes; `git-bash` just means that it's someone's *port* of bash *to* Windows, included with a Git distribution), `set GIT_SSH` doesn't set `GIT_SSH`, it sets the positional arguments. `set one two three` sets `$1` to `one`, `$2` to `two`, and `$3` to `three`. To *see* what `GIT_SSH` is set to, use `echo $GIT_SSH`.

Comment: I avoid Windows, but I do know that *modern* Windows has its own ssh, and Git-for-Windows comes with *its* own ssh so that it can run on older Windows version, and this causes endless pain now because the two ssh versions are just different enough to, well, cause endless pain. :-) I suspect you're right about Git Extensions here, it's trying to use one and getting the other, or something.

Comment: In bash, to set-and-export `GIT_SSH` (as any particular value), use `export GIT_SSH=<value>`. Be careful if `<value>` has any shell metacharacters (spaces, tabs, asterisks, quotes, etc) as then bash itself will try to interpret the metacharacter. You'll need to use quotes (single or double depending on context), e.g., export GIT_SSH="C:/path with space/to/program" might work.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. The GIT_SSH environment variable is set in Window. I don't quite get what `export GIT_SSH` is for. I don't need git to export anything anywhere, I need it to use the variable and use putty instead of anything else.

Comment: The above are just general comments about using bash. If things are already set correctly, that's fine: I'm just saying that if you want to *see* what `GIT_SSH` is set to, *do not run* `set GIT_SSH` in bash, it won't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows is a recent Windows 10, you don't need pagent/putty anymore.

Simply make sure your `%PATH%` includes the packaged OpenSSH included with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

Test it in a CMD with:

```sh
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%
where ssh
set GIT_SSH=
```

The second command should print `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`.
The third should empty `GIT_SSH`

From that CMD, try again your SSH URLs.
You can open a bash from that CMD by simply typing `bash`. (remain in the same CMD to inherit your `%PATH%` changes).

If you have old putty SSH keys, regenerate new ones (still from that CMD) with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/myKey1
```

Then in `~/.ssh/config`

Host myRepo1
Hostname /url/to/repo1
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myKey1

Test it with:

```
git ls-remote myRepo1
```

Then check the [GitExtension documentation "Remotes/ OpenSSH and github"](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/release-3.4/remote_feature.html#openssh-and-github), and try using OpenSSH instead of putty keys.

Comment: Thanks but I have all my keys compatible with putty, there's a lot of them and I want to keep using it. More importantly, how come GitExtensions is able to use pageant and I can't? How do they do it?

Comment: @masiton Not sure. I haven't used putty keys in year.